# Scrollbar in the correct div

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with an events list, that show the title and the date. when I click it (is a  )go to an other page with a list of events (with a repeater) but with description etc. my question is how I can the scrollbar be in the div that I clicked? 
I tried with Focus and Set Focus, but it doesn't work, maybe I do something wrong but i have no idea what.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plEvents" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rItems" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" 
                Visible='<%#GetVisibleFocus(((IPublishedContent)Container.DataItem))%>'>
                <a id="focushere"></a>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            <div>...
```

cs and doesn't found the focushere

```
this.Page.SetFocus(focushere)
```

Comment: Nobody can help you without your code. Please post your code and somebody can find out what your doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing problem because you have id of anchor set to focushere and your anchor is in a repeater. So if repeater has 10 entries then all of them will have same id and browser will not focus on correct as per your command.

What you can do is set some dynamic id for anchor inside repeater like this

```
<a id="focushere<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"></a>
```

and set focus on specific anchor id like this

```
this.Page.SetFocus("focushere1")
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more question, i'm so confused right now :/ the setfocus where i have to put it? because some say in the Page_Load and other say that it's the same :/

Comment: Yes you can place it in page_load. Actually this need to place on any function before page get render and most preferred location could be page_load because this event is always created on code behind in visual studio.

Comment: Thaaank you :D now i have an other problem :/ that is "is not a valid identifier." I did this to identify the focus: id="focushere<%#((IPublishedContent)Container.DataItem).Id%>"